# How to put data in the section of Data Variables in a file netCDF using xarray

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

## Problem

I am coding a program that reads an excel file and extracts the data and puts it into a netcdf file, the problem is that I can't get the data into the Data Variables section. I use xarray and pandas for that. Here is my code:

```
# Ouvrir le xlsx
df = pd.read_excel('./data/data_example/dd.xlsx')

col_names = df.columns.tolist()

col_names_clean = []

col_units = []

col_names_no_unit = []

for col_name in col_names:

    if "(" in col_name and "Beta" not in col_name:
        col_unit = col_name[col_name.find("(")+1:col_name.find(")")]
        col_name = col_name.replace("("+col_unit+")", "")
        col_units.append(col_unit)
    else:
        col_names_no_unit.append(col_name)

global_attributes = {
    'title': 'Data from Guyane',
    'institution': 'CNRS',
    'source': 'Data from Guyane',
    'history': 'Created by the CNRS',
    'references': 'https://www.cnrs.fr/',
    'comment': 'Data from Guyane',
    'Conventions': 'CF-1.6',
}

col_values1 = []
for col_name in col_names_clean:
    col_values1.append(sorted(list(set(df[col_name+"("+col_names_units[col_name]+")"]))))
    
col_values2 = []
# On parcours la liste des noms de colonnes
for col_name in col_names_no_unit:
    # On ajoute les valeurs de la colonne dans la liste des valeurs
    col_values2.append(sorted(list(set(df[col_name]))))

# On créé un dictionnaire pour stocker les noms des colonnes et les valeurs 
col_names_values2 = dict(zip(col_names_no_unit, col_values2))

# On créé la dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(
    coords = {
        # On prend les valeurs de col_names_values en fonction du nom
        col_name: (col_name, col_names_values[col_name]) for col_name in col_names_clean
    },  
# Here the problem :
    data_vars= {col_name: (col_name, col_names_values2[col_name]) for col_name in col_names_no_unit},
    attrs = global_attributes
)
```

This is what I get when I run the code, I just want it to say in the Coordinates section : Time, Pres, Temp Cond, Sal, CHL. I don't understand why the variables get put there. Does anyone have a solution?

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (_G100_: 1, _G125_: 1, _G150_: 1, bbp_VSF_532: 1113,
                  Beta(488): 146, Beta(510): 38, Beta(532): 1, Beta(595): 1,
                  Beta(650): 194, Beta(676): 1, Beta(715): 1, Beta(765): 1,
                  Beta(865): 1, bbp488: 1148, bbp510: 1136, bbp532: 1113,
                  bbp595: 1081, bbp650: 1130, bbp676: 1101, bbp715: 1111,
                  bbp765: 258, bbp865: 258, CDOM-ppb: 283, a401: 1175,
                  ...
                  c716: 1064, c717: 1064, c718: 1064, c719: 1066, c720: 1066,
                  c721: 1066, c722: 1066, c723: 1068, c724: 1068, c725: 1068,
                  c726: 1068, c727: 1075, c728: 1075, c729: 1075, c730: 1075,
                  c731: 1083, c732: 1083, c733: 1083, c734: 1083, c735: 1011,
                  c736: 1090, Time: 1317, Pres: 126, Temp: 201, Cond: 219,
                  Sal: 258, CHL: 54)
Coordinates: (12/701)
  * _G100_       (_G100_) float64 55
  * _G125_       (_G125_) float64 55
  * _G150_       (_G150_) float64 55
  * bbp_VSF_532  (bbp_VSF_532) float64 55
  * Beta(488)    (Beta(488)) float64 55
  * Beta(510)    (Beta(510)) float64 55
...
  * Time         (Time) int32 55 55
  * Pres         (Pres) float64 55
  * Temp         (Temp) float64 55
  * Cond         (Cond) float64 55
  * Sal          (Sal) float64 55
  * CHL          (CHL) float64 55
Data variables:
    *empty*
Attributes:
    title:        Data from Guyane
    institution:  CNRS
    source:       Data from Guyane
    history:      Created by the CNRS
    references:   https://www.cnrs.fr/
    comment:      Data from Guyane
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
```

## Solution :

You just need to put a "description" to your variable so that it fits in the data_variable section. Like for example :

```
for i in col_names_clean:
        # On ajoute les valeurs de la colonne dans le dictionnaire coords
        coords[i] = ("Coords", col_names_values[i])
    
    # On créé une dataset avec toutes les valeurs et on y met dans la section Data Variables
    ds = xr.Dataset(
        coords=coords,
        
        data_vars={
            i: ("Variables", col_names_values2[i]) for i in col_names_no_unit
        },
        attrs=global_attributes
    )
```

And here the result in the terminal :

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (Variables: 1317, Coords: 1317)
Coordinates:
    Time         (Coords) int32 55
    Pres         (Coords) float64 55
    Temp         (Coords) float64 55 29.98
    Cond         (Coords) float64 55
    Sal          (Coords) float64 55 26.95
    CHL          (Coords) float64 55
Dimensions without coordinates: Variables, Coords
Data variables: (12/695)
    _G100_       (Variables) float64 55
    _G125_       (Variables) float64 55 
    _G150_       (Variables) float64 55
    bbp_VSF_532  (Variables) float64 55
    Beta(488)    (Variables) float64 55
    Beta(510)    (Variables) float64 55
    ...           ...
    c731         (Variables) float64 355
    c732         (Variables) float64 55
    c733         (Variables) float64 55
    c734         (Variables) float64 55
    c735         (Variables) float64 55
    c736         (Variables) float64 55
Attributes:
    title:        Data from Guyane
    institution:  CNRS
    source:       Data from Guyane
    history:      Created by the CNRS
    references:   https://www.cnrs.fr/
    comment:      Data from Guyane
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
```

Comment: please don't remove the original question, this makes it no longer useful for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood properly your question, but it seems you have a confusion between data variables and dimensions. When using `xarray.Dataset`, you should indicate dimensions as arguments, instead of repeating `col_name`.

So, instead of:

```
data_vars= {col_name: (col_name, col_names_values2[col_name]) for col_name in col_names_no_unit}
```

I would suggest you to use:

```
data_vars= {col_name: (["Time", "Pres", "Temp Cond", "Sal", "CHL"], col_names_values2[col_name]) for col_name in col_names_no_unit}
```

or shortly

```
data_vars= {col_name: (col_names_clean, col_names_values2[col_name]) for col_name in col_names_no_unit}
```

if I understand well.

Nevertheless, you may be more precise in your question by indicating what are your dimensions, coordinates and variables and how they relate to `col_names_clean` and `col_names_no_unit`.

Comment: I explained it wrong, sorry. I don't want to put ["Time", "Pres", "Temp Cond", "Sal", "CHL"] in the variables section but those in the col_names_no_unit list with their associated values

Comment: `["Time", "Pres", "Temp Cond", "Sal", "CHL"]` will not be considered as data variables but as the dimensions of your variables, as they are in the first part of the tuple. Only the second part of the tuple, here `col_names_values2[col_name]`, will be considered as data values, under the variable name `col_name` (for all `col_name` in `col_names_no_unit` as you wrote).

I expect this would yield a dataset with dimensions and coordinates closer to what you want, does it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do but I don't understand why my values other than ```["Time", "Pres", "Temp Cond", "Sal", "CHL"]``` get put in the dimensions section when I want to use them.

Comment: As I see from your example, you have defined all your variables as coordinates, meaning that they take themselves as dimensions: you have assigned the dimension `_G100_` to your variable `_G100_`, and so on, because you assign the dimension `col_name` to the values `col_names_values2[col_name]`.

Comment: But the ```col_name``` is an iteration on the table ```col_names_value2```, so like that i have the "clean" variables. I don't understand how to solve my problem, I try so many things but the result is always the same..

Comment: Could you please show the results you have obtained with the first answer I gave you?

Comment: I have found the solution I will edit my message to put it